# Call proper subclass method after previous cast to superclass type

Tags: java

Assume you have a base class BC with subclasses SC1, SC2, ... and a collection C of objects (some of type SC1 and some of type SC2, ...).  A method m is defined in the subclasses, NOT in BC.  I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
class AnotherClass {
  private BC getObj(Container c) { /*return something from c*/ }

  private void anotherMethod() {
    ...
    BC o = getObj(c);
    o.m();
  }
}
```

Now getObj will return a reference o to an object and as far as I know it must be of type BC (or is there a way to apply generics here?).  I get a compile error as is (m() doesn't exist in BC).  I'm assuming there is there a nice way to do this (without having to "manually" figure out the real type of o somehow)?

Comment: can you provide more detail. What exactly is o?

Comment: *(m() doesn't exist in BC)* Looks like you found your problem.

Comment: If I understand right, You can check the instance of the baseclass, cast it accordingly and then call .m()

Comment: This is really confusing. In order to give a proper answer we totally need more details.

Comment: Not at all; this is basic Java: you either use polymorphism, implement an interface, check the type, or use reflection. In this case polymorphism or an interface are the clear choice, and I'd vote for polymorphism with a default implementation if some subclasses don't need specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Why isn't the method defined in `BC`? This is what polymorphism is all about.

Your other option is to have the objects implement an interface that contains `m` and have a collection of that interface instead of `BC`. Or use reflection (ew), or check the type (ew).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BC 
{
    protected void m()
    {
        System.out.println("BC:M");
    }

}


public class SC1 extends BC 
{
    public void m()
    {
        super.m();
        System.out.println("SC1:M");

    }

}


public class SC2 extends BC 
{
    public void m()
    {
        super.m();
        System.out.println("SC2:M");

    }

}


public class TestClass 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SC1 sc1_one= new SC1();
        SC1 sc1_two= new SC1();

        SC2 sc2_one= new SC2();
        SC2 sc2_two= new SC2();
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList<BC>();
        al.add(sc1_one);
        al.add(sc2_one);
        al.add(sc1_two);
        al.add(sc2_two);

        BC bc = (BC) al.get(3);
        bc.m();
    }

}
```

ouput : 
BC:M
SC2:M

For these scenario you need to declare method m inside the base class. then you can override into subclasses

Answer (score 0):

At this point

```
BC o = getObj(c);
```

You have a reference, o, to an object. At compile time, the only thing your code knows for a fact is that whatever this reference points to (BC, or subclasses of BC) has the methods defined in BC. It can't know that the subclass you've given it is an instance of SC1 or SC2. So, your issue is that you need to execute methods only defined on the subclasses. You have a few options here.

1. Reflection - Use Java's reflection capability to inspect the object you're given, see if the method is available, then call it. But you lose compile time checking, and this is slow. Not a preferred solution
2. Check the instance of c, cast to the appropriate type, then call the methods. This will work, but instanceof is also slow, and defeats the purpose of subclassing and polymorphism. Also not recommended.
3. Introduce a method (perhaps abstract if BC never needs to be instantiated) into BC that your subclasses then override. Call this method directly. This is the better solution and is probably what you should be going for.
4. As above, but use an interface that your subclasses implement, and have your method return that interface.